# NSMutableData SetLength error

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller, nsurlconnection

My app gets some json data from a server and it uses a NSMUtableData object to store these data.
But debugger is reporting the following error:

```
[NSCFString setLength:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

and the debugger highlighted the following line (in connection didReceiveResponse method):

```
[rqst_data setLength:0];
```

rqst_data is declared as NSMutableData in header file.

Thx in advance for your kind help,

Stephane

Comment: Why are you setting the length to `0`? Also, are you sure you have initialized the `rqst_data` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your `rqst_data` variable gets released. Make sure you have properly allocated it. If you have declared `@property` for it you better use the variable as `self.rqst_data`.
You can use `retain` and in case of IOS 5 `strong` in property declaration.

You can track if any variable gets released via setting `NSZombieEnabled` to `YES`. With zombies enabled, messages to deallocated objects will no longer behave strangely or crash in difficult-to-understand ways, but will instead log a message and die in a predictable and debugger-breakpointable way. 
You can set `NSZombieEnabled` by the following steps.

Select Product from the menu bar above. Keep alt/option pressed and select "Test..." or "Run...".

1.
Go to the Arguments tab, and add `NSZombieEnabled` `YES` in the "Environment Variables" section.

OR

2.
Go to the Diagnostics tab, and check `Enable Zombie Objects` in the "Memory Management" section.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your rqst_data pointer is actually pointer to an NSString, not an NSMutableData object.  And you can't set the length of a NSString.

Perhaps you have not retained the NSMutableData object or have overreleased it so that the pointer to it is no longer valid.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was setting this variable with a string. Thank you very much for helping!